# Extreme slow PC if logged on as domain user remotely

Tags: windows, windows-xp, active-directory, users

I'm using windows XP to do the development.

Since I working remotely from home, I found a serous problem, some applications for instance MS excel, even just open up the start menu or My computer became to extremely slow .

If I logged into the local pc without domain then the problem fixed, my domain user account has 300 mb local user profile.

Anybody know how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Where does your "My Documents" path refer to?  Is Offline Files enabled on the machine?  Do you have a VPN connection to your workplace network running?

Comment: Don't know where to set the offline files , my documents refer to a network drive on my domain server.

I have a VPN to my work, that's how I working remotely.

Answer (score 1):

Network drives mapped to shares that are not accessible while working remotely can cause this.  Look to see if you have any mapped and if so try disconnecting them to see if this resolves your problem.

Comment: It helps in some of the cases, but still found have problem going to my Documents, I think I'd better move the my documents from domain server to my local drive. Thanks for answer anyway.